Memory error starting clamav daemon after install
I use Linux Mint 22 x86_64 with 6.8.0-45-generic kernel. I installed the latest version of clamav antivirus (1.4.1), but suddenly a problem appeared after restart clamav-daemon:
LibClamAV Error: Can't load daily.wdb: Can't allocate memory.
Full systemctl status clamav-daemon output:
clamd[81500]: LibClamAV Warning: ***   Please update it as soon as possible.    ***
clamd[81500]: LibClamAV Warning: **************************************************
clamd[81500]: LibClamAV Error: Can't load daily.wdb: Can't allocate memory
clamd[81500]: LibClamAV Error: cli_tgzload: Can't load daily.wdb
clamd[81500]: LibClamAV Error: Can't load /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld: Malformed database
clamd[81500]: LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir: error loading database /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld
clamd[81500]: ERROR: Thu Oct  3 04:19:55 2024 -> Malformed database
systemd[1]: clamav-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: clamav-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: clamav-daemon.service: Consumed 1.425s CPU time.

How to fix this? I didn't find any memory limits in freshclam.conf or clamd.conf.
What I tried to do:

Manipulating the ulimit -d, -v, -s parameters did not give anything.
Set ConcurrentDatabaseReload parameter (clamd.conf) to no didn't help either.


Try running freshclam to reload the databases.  I don't know if it's causing the memory issue,  but the Malformed database messages are definitly a problem.
